# Let $F/K,F'/K'$ be two galois extensions(maybe infinite), $F\subset F',K\subset K'$, is $G(F'/K')\to G(F/K)$ via restriction open map?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

$\textbf{Q:}$ Let $F/K,F'/K'$ be two galois extensions(maybe infinite), $F\subset F',K\subset K'$, is $G(F'/K')\to G(F/K)$ via restriction open map? $G(E/F)$ denotes galois group of $E/F$ field extension.

It is clear that $G(F'/K')\to G(F/(F'\cap K))$ is open surjective map. However, it is not clear that $G(F/(F'\cap K))\to G(F'/K')$ is open but it is continuous.

Comment: If $F'=K'$ and $G(F/K)$ is infinite, then the map is not open.

Comment: @user363120 what is the criterion for openess of the map here? I need the image of basic open set around 1 to be basic open set which asserts that the $F'\cap K$ to be finite galois over $K$. Is this the condition for any such map to be open?

Comment: @user363120 The map you give is not open for sure as its fixed field is $F$ which is not finite extension over $K$ for $G(F/K)$ infinte case.